# jquery clear values of all input fields except one

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to write a script which clears the value of all input fields except for one.  This script is still clearing the DESCRIPTION input field.

```
jQuery('.campaign-column').not('active').each(function(index){
    if(jQuery('.campaign-column input[name!="DESCRIPTION"]')){
        jQuery(this+':input').val('');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplify:

```
$('.campaign-column:not(.active) input:not([name="DESCRIPTION"])').val('')
```

I assume you meant `.not('.active')` and not `.not('active')`, since there is no `<active>` element in HTML. Note, the loop (`.each()`) in your original code is pointless, since every iteration selects, over and over, the same elements.

Comment: @user1413248 its a css selector so its looking for a child input of .campaign-column which is why there is a space there.

Comment: Wow this is great!!  The only thing is its not clearing the value of DESCRIPTION in .campaign-column:not(.active).  It should clear this for everything except ones that have a class 'active'.

Comment: @user1413248 is the class active on the input or its parent?

Comment: @user1413248 so you _do_ want it to clear the `<input name="DESCRIPTION"/>` field's value? Just remove the `:not([name="DESCRIPTION"])` part of the selector. I was taking a guess based on your original selector.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write a each loop in this case.. Try this

```
$(function(){
    // Select all text fields but not Description field..   

    var $txtfields = $('.campaign-column:not(.active)').find('input[type=text][name!=DESCRIPTION]')

    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
       $txtfields.val('')  ;
    });
});​
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wh3W7/) for working example

Comment: This was a much better option for my needs

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') != 'source_url'){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.